Python script not returning results from MSSQL stored procedure, despite successful execution
I'm encountering an issue with retrieving results from an MSSQL stored procedure using a Python script. Here's the problem:
I have a stored procedure getlive_value in my MSSQL database XStudio_Historian. When I execute this stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio using the query execute XStudio_Historian.[dbo].getlive_value '45', it returns a value as expected.
However, when I attempt to execute the same stored procedure from a Python script using the pyodbc library, it executes successfully but doesn't return any results.
Here's the Python script I'm using:
import pyodbc

# Database connection details
driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'
server = 'MIS-SRV'
database = 'XStudio_Historian'
username = 'username'
password = 'database_password'

# Stored procedure to execute
stored_proc_name = 'getlive_value'
parameter = '45'

# Connection string
conn_str = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'

try:
    # Connect to the database
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
    print("Connected to the database.")

    # Create a cursor
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Execute the stored procedure
    cursor.execute(f"EXEC {database}.[dbo].{stored_proc_name} '{parameter}'")
    print("Stored procedure executed successfully.")

    # Fetch the results if any
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)

    # Close cursor and connection
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    print("Connection closed.")
    
except pyodbc.Error as ex:
    print(f"Error: {ex}")

I've checked the stored procedure, and it does return results when executed directly in MSSQL.

What could be causing this discrepancy between executing the stored procedure in MSSQL and Python? And how can I modify my Python script to retrieve the expected results?
Python Error is as shown in the image :
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You might need: SET NOCOUNT ON in the procedure

As a side note, if you are connecting to {Database} there is no reason to then include {Database} in the object's name.

Also you really should be using the latest ODBC driver; SQLNCLI was deprecated in 2012 and discontinued in 2014.

CAUTION: The use of string interpolation (f-strings) to insert parameter values into your SQL statement leaves your code open to a SQL injection attack.

Ahh, the irony, @TN , that '{parameter}' is anything but parametrised.
